# Custom section heading in shopify liquid

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm wanting to create simple custom liquid section headings on my shopify site. I'm using the code below which does part of the job, but I'm unsure how to make further changes...

- Border above (not below)
- Less padding
- Custom text link

Some visual cues

- [What it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm23q.png)
- [What I'm aiming for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWCAW.png)

```
<h2 class="rich-text__title text-block__item text-block__heading type-heading-1" style="border-top: 1px; margin-top:0px;" >
        RECENTLY ADDED
      </h2>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this...

```css
.border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-top">
  <h2 class="rich-text__title text-block__item text-block__heading type-heading-1">RECENTLY ADDED</h2>
  <a href="#">Shop All</a>
</div>
```